# Who says Barchu at the end of davening?

Tags: tefilla, eretz-yisrael

Here in Israel, at the end of Shacharit most days, and Maariv all the time, someone says *Barchu*. In Nusach Sefard, it's before *Aleinu*; after in Nusach Ashkenaz. It is generally said by someone who just said *Kaddish*, though if no one said it, the chazzan does.

When there are multiple people who said Kaddish, how do they know which one should say Barchu? Usually there is no conflict; someone just says it. Once in a while there'll be two, or someone will need prompting. But in the average case, who is supposed to say it, that the others let him?

Comment: Why not everyone say it just like everyone says Kaddish?

Comment: I think it's improper for multiple people to say it. But regardless, i'm asking about how i've actually observed it done.

Comment: Edot Hamizrach have the custom for all those who said Kaddish to say Barchu.

Comment: @Epicentre Thinking back on it, i think that's true. However, other nuschaot have just one person say it.

Comment: @Scimonster Indeed. Our Rav (nusach sfarad)  allows only 1 (although with a mixed congregation it doesn't always succeed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's usually some unwritten rule for this. Something like:

- Some Aveilim are Makpid to say both Borchu's - so they always *take* it.
- Or else it's given to the *unlucky* fellow who didn't get to be Chazzan - since the Chazzan already said a Borchu. If there's no 2nd *chiyuv* then the Chazzan will say it.
- If a Sefardi also said Kaddish, and he's anyways going to say Borchu,  then the other candidates don't say it.

And if you look carefully, there's usually a conversation going on between the Kaddish-sayers - using head-nodding - while they are saying (or right after) that final Kaddish.

Answer (score 1):

The [Mishna Berura (132:10)](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.132.9?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) makes little distinction in the importance of a mourner not only saying kaddish, but Barchu as well. It could very well be that just as many mourners can say kaddish in unison, so too can individuals say Barchu together:

> י) **קדיש יתום אחר עלינו** - שהרי לעולם צריכין לומר קדיש אחר שאמרו פסוקים
>   ובעלינו יש ג"כ פסוקים וצריכים קדיש אחריו אלא שנהגו בקדיש זה להניחו
>   ליתום שמת אביו ואמו מפני שיש יתומים קטנים או אפילו גדולים שאינם יכולים
>   להיות שלוחי ציבור **ולומר קדיש וברכו** אחר אביו ואמו [שאם היו יכולים
>   להתפלל לפני העמוד זהו טוב יותר מאמירת קדיש] וכבר ידוע ממעשה דר' עקיבא
>   תועלת הגדול שיש למת כשיש לו בן האומר **קדיש וברכו** וביותר בתוך שנה ראשונה
>   לכך תקנו והניחו קדיש זה שאין צריך שום דבר יותר ליתומים הן קטנים הן
>   גדולים.